# Good ways to connect to database with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, database-connection, connection-string

Good day to all,

I'm new to programming and I'm building like a simple program. Just buttons and display the results. This is how I connect to database. I used MySQL.data.dll and add it as reference.

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;database=super;uid=root;password=root";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE idPeople=1";
conn.Open();
// get data
conn.Close()
```

What other ways are there to connect to a database, like a good practice perhaps, a better way. It would be great if you could help me improve my programming level. Sorry if you find this question dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb399572.aspx)

Comment: it depends up to your application

Answer (score 2):

That's on the right track, but you're missing a couple important points:

1. You aren't closing your connection correctly. If your sql statement throws an exception, you'll never reach the .Close() call. Depending on your database type and how it's configured, this can result in maxing out your db server's available connections and effectively locking yourself out of your own database.
2. Where did the "1" come from in "idPeople=1"? There is a right way and a wrong way to build queries containing argument data like that "1". Make sure you do it the right way.
3. "SELECT *" is considered bad form... much better to specify the column list.

Here is an example that solves all these issues:

```
//often this will loaded from a config file
string connString = "Server=localhost;database=super;uid=root;password=root";

string sql = "SELECT <column list> FROM people WHERE idPeople= @idPeople";
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
uinsg (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@idPeople", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 1;

    conn.Open();
    //get data
}
```

You'll see some people tell you to use an ORM, like NHibernate, linq-to-sql, Entity Framework, etc. I tend to think there's still a place for hand-coded and tuned sql, and I don't pay much attention to them. A light-weight data access framework like [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) can be helpful, though. These can abstract away much of the boilerplate code not only from what I just wrote, but also the business and transport object layers, and still let you write whatever sql you need.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you very much! Didn't thought about that way. I guess I still need some reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you are going to use an ORM like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Comment: I see. I just want to know the best ways to connect to a database and some techniques in building system with database. And thank you for the link. I'll definitely read it!

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you think of connetion to the database using c#, there are three types.

1. connected- is a way of accessing the database by opening and closing the connection. That is, you are accessing the database directly by SQL commands.
2. disconnected- is, for example, using store procedures instead of directly accessing the database using the SQL commands.
3. Entity Framework- is a framework that does the connection of the database on behalf of you. You only need to configure it once and accessibility is much flexible through class objects. This framework is best also in using LINQ.

I recommend you to read the book titled with "Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 plateform" 5th edition by Andrew Troelsen. [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 plateform](http://www.apress.com/9781430225492). you can get the latest version.

There is also another framework called NHibernate which is almost similar to Hibernate in Java